# How to display incoming emails to a website?

Tags: parsing, email

I want to display the incoming emails on my website.
I have three web based email accounts (on gmail) and I want to display the content of each incoming email coming to these accounts on my website.
Is there a tool or cloud based service to do it.?
Heard about Wordpress POSTIE but it works on one email I guess.
Does amazon ses help me implement this?

I am also open to buy gmail app if this is achievable by it.

I am not much into technical but will outsource if this is achievable in minimum amount of money..
Thanks in anticipation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You can use Perl module [Mail::POP3Client](http://search.cpan.org/~sdowd/Mail-POP3Client-2.16/POP3Client.pm).*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::SSL;
use Mail::POP3Client;

my $username  = '...@gmail.com';
my $password  = '...';

my $mailhost  = 'pop.gmail.com';
my $port      = '995';

my $pop = new Mail::POP3Client(
            USER     => $username,
            PASSWORD => $password,
            HOST     => $mailhost,
            PORT     => $port,
            USESSL   => 'true',
            DEBUG    => 0,
);

for (my $i = 1; $i <= $pop->Count(); $i++) {
  my $message = $pop->Body($i);
  ...
}

$pop->Close();
```